# Unable to receive ajax request in codeIgniter PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have just started codeigniter and I am stuck at sending employee ID to my controller.

Actually, I have a datatable which shows all the registered employees, and there is a button which get the ID of the employee of row clicked and send it to controller through ajax call but i am unable to receive it in my ajax call.

**JS code**

```
$('#viewAllEmployeeTable tbody').on('click', '.viewEmployeeDetail', function() {
    var data = viewAllEmployeeTable.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
    console.log(data);
    employeeID = data.employeeID;
    alert(employeeID);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ackamarackus/employee/viewEmployeeProfile",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            "employeeID": employeeID
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function viewEmployeeProfile() {
    $name =  $this->input->post('employeeID');
    echo "INPUT";
    echo $name;
    die();
}
```

This is what ajax is sending : `employeeID:1000`

Can anyone tell me what I am doing here? I have already tried google and stack overflow link, but nothing solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send field `data` with `type: 'GET'`
Change this to `type:'POST'` and this will solve your issue :)

Comment: My mistake, I didn't even bother to look at this :/

Comment: @BilalZafar sometimes it happens with everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

You are sending employeeID as `GET` method and accessing it as `POST` in Your controller, change your type in ajax request to `POST` as follows

```
$('#viewAllEmployeeTable tbody').on('click', '.viewEmployeeDetail', function() {
    var data = viewAllEmployeeTable.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
    console.log(data);
    employeeID = data.employeeID;
    alert(employeeID);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ackamarackus/employee/viewEmployeeProfile",
        type: "POST", //Your problem here
        data: {
            "employeeID": employeeID
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```